# Как сделать чтоб админ получал сообщение от пользователя? telebot

Tags: python, telebot

Я сделал код: если в чат написать `смс` то введёная пользователем фраза должна пересылаться админу

```
def sms(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '❗ПРЕДУПРЕЖДЕНИЕ:❗\nПри спаме вы навсегда потеряете доступ к боту на данном аккаунте!')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Напишите вашу идею для проекта.')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, sms_global)
    return

def sms_global(message):
    user_guess = message.text

    print('Кто-то отправил вам смс')
    bot.send_message(config_reader.admin_id, user_guess)
    print(user_guess)
    return
```

Но это сообщение отправляется обратно пользователю который это сообщение написал. Можно ли это реализовать небольшой строчкой кода, чтоб не морочить голову с этим? Бот в целом нужен только для отправление медиа файлов, а такая функция нужна чтоб пользователи могли отправлять идеи проектов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перепроверил код. У меня всё отлично работает. Возможно проблема находится, в указанном вами `config_reader.admin_id`, потому что, если подставить id канала вручную, то введённый вами текст успешно выводится в этот канал.

```python
@bot.message_handler(commands=['sms'])
def sms(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     '❗ПРЕДУПРЕЖДЕНИЕ:❗\nПри спаме вы навсегда потеряете доступ к боту на данном аккаунте!')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Напишите вашу идею для проекта.')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, sms_global)


def sms_global(message):
    user_guess = message.text
    print('Кто-то отправил вам смс')
    bot.send_message('id вашего канала', user_guess)
    print(user_guess)
```

Попробуйте ещё раз указать id канала в строке, где я оставил `'id вашего канала'`. Могу предположить, что вы указали свой же id и тестировали в одном чате, поэтому вам и присылает туда же, откуда и было отправлено сообщение. P.S. чуть-чуть подправил код.